# Collection of different types of data in a relational database

Tags: database-design, relational-theory, data-collection

Let's say I have a table `Cars` (with columns such as `model`, `make`, `year`, etc.), a table `Books` (with columns such as `name`, `author`, `ISBN`, etc.) and a table `Wines` (with columns such as `name`, `appellation`, `region`, `vintage`, etc.)

Now, even if these tables don't seem related at all, I want to make a collection of all these things called "My favorites things in the world". In this list, I will find cars, books and wines.

If I only wanted to have lists of cars, I would create a table called `Car_Lists` with `id` and `name` + a table called `Car_List_Items` with `id`, `car_list_id` (foreign key to the `id` in the table `Car_Lists`) and `car_id` (foreign key to the `id` in the table `Cars`).

Here, as I want to have a list of different types of things, I don't really see how this could be done.

So my question: How would I represent that with a relational database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, depending on the requirements. That being said, this sounds like a homework question which is designed to make *you* think about it.

However, one way to do it would be to create a table that contains columns that occur in all the different types. Then create a table for each unique type that contains information specific to that type.

Then in your list table you can just create a foreign key to the base table (in this example "things")

```
create table "things"
(
    id int identity not null primary key
    -- add shared columns here
);
create table "cars"
(
    id int not null,
    -- add car details here
    constraint fk_cars_id foreign key (id) references "things" (id)
);
create table "myfavoritethings"
(
     id int not null,
     constraint fk_myfavoritethings foreign key "things" (id)
);
```

I prefer this approach because you can maintain referential integrity. Also, you are able to create a nice view from it like so knowing that the id's are unique across all type tables:

```
create view "vw_myfavoritethings"
as
select t.id
     , -- add car fields here
  from "things" as t
  join "cars" as c on c.id = t.id
  -- additional joins to type tables
  join "myfavoritethings" as mft on mft.id = t.id;
```

Another way you could do it would be to just create your individual tables and then just store the id's and type in your list table like so:

```
create table "myfavoritethings"
(
    id int not null primary key
);
```

If you use this design it would be recommended to create a sequence and then use that to generate your primary key id's across all type tables to ensure that the id value is unique. You can of course use auto increments/identities on each table but then you would need to work out what id = 1 refers to in your list yourself.

Comment: @Vinch no problem - remember to mark the question as answered if this helped you.